# Yii Redactor with S3 Upload

Tags: yii, amazon-s3, redactor

Currently I am using this Imperavi Redactor widget with my Yii Install. https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget. It currently works but then I noticed I can handle image uploading through the WYSIWYG so I looked on how to enable that which lead me to this:

```
<?php 
    $attribute = 'info';
    $this->widget('ImperaviRedactorWidget', array(
        // The textarea selector
        'selector' => '.redactor',
        // Options
        'options'=>array(
            'fileUpload'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('post/fileUpload',array(
                'attr'=>$attribute
            )),
            'fileUploadErrorCallback'=>new CJavaScriptExpression(
                'function(obj,json) { alert(json.error); }'
            ),
            'imageUpload'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('post/imageUpload',array(
                'attr'=>$attribute
            )),
            'imageGetJson'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('post/imageList',array(
                'attr'=>$attribute
            )),
            'imageUploadErrorCallback'=>new CJavaScriptExpression(
                'function(obj,json) { alert(json.error); }'
            ),
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

but then I dug through redactor.js and noticed that they're S3 functions but currently not sure how to use them as I could not find documentation anywhere about it just standard image uploading. Has anyone ever used this? If so could you lead me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Redactor's "S3" directions leave alot to the imagination and just does not seem to work. So I took my own approach.

```
$this->widget('ImperaviRedactorWidget', array(
        // The textarea selector
        'selector' => '.redactor',
        // Some options, see http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/
        'options'=>array(   
            'fileUpload'=>'../upload',
             'Upload'=>'../upload',
                ),
    ));
```

Created an upload action in the controller.

```
public function actionUpload(){
            $S3_KEY = '';
        $S3_SECRET = '';
        $S3_BUCKET = ''; 

        $S3_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/';

        // expiration date of query
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $s3 = new A2S3();
        $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $S3_BUCKET,
            'Key'    => $filename,
            'Body'   => fopen($tempFile, 'r+'),
            'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        ));

        $array = array(
        'filelink' => 'http://'.$S3_BUCKET.$filename
        );

        echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
```